# Referential integrity constraint violation error on Deletion (Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

What I wanted to achieve is, when deletion is performed on `User` table, automatically `NotificationDetails` table should delete the object mapped with the user. However, the operation fails showing *"Referential integrity constraint violation error"* when testing using H2-console.

#### `User` class (parent class)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "Username",unique = true,nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "Password",nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "user")
    private NotificationDetails notificationDetails;
......
.......

}
```

#### `NotificationDetails` class

```
@Entity
public class NotificationDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String notificationPushToken;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: remove the reference of User from NotificationDetails.class and  add @JoinColumn(name = "Notification_details_ID", referencedColumnName = "id") to User#notificationDetails. This will make NotificationDetails a privately owned object of User Class.

Comment: By doing so will create an additional column in User table to store Notification IDs right? I dont want that to happen. What I wanted is the Notification Table to hold the User ids as the Reference Column....

Comment: Your initial comment says "What I wanted to achieve is, when deletion is performed on User Table, automatically NotificationDetails Table should delete object mapped with the User." So User Object has to privately own(Design concept) the NotificationDetails(Solution I suggested). If the User reference is there in NotificationDetails, then you have to write custom code to delete it. If later, I would say, please re-think the design. All with consideration to want to achieve OneToOne Relationship only.